# Create a query using LINQ to entities with 1:N relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I know it's not something unusual to make such kind of queries but I think I get lost so I seek help. I have to tables with relation 1:N and to make it more clear I'll post a print screen from the management studio :

[image: Table relation]

I am working on a asp.net mvc 3 project and I need to make a view where all `Documents` will be shown (and some filter and stuff, but I think that is irrelevant for this case). I need the data from the table `Documents` and only one specific record for each document from the `DocumentFields` table. This record is the record holding the name of the Document and it's uniqueness is DocumentID == Docmuents.Id, DocumentFields.RowNo == 1 and DocumentsFields.ColumnNo == 2. This is unique record for every Document and I need to get the `FieldValue` from this record which actually holds the Name of the Document.

I am not very sure how to build my query (maybe using JOIN) and I also would like to make my view strongly typed passing a model of type `Documents` but I'm not sure if it's possible, but I think depending on the way the query is build will determine the type of the model for the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is something like this:

```
var results = 
    from d in dbContext.Documents
    join df in dbContext.DocumentFields 
    on new { d.Id, RowNo = 1, ColumnNo = 2 } equals 
       new { Id = df.DocumentId, df.RowNo, df.ColumnNo }
    select new 
    {
        Document = d,
        DocumentName = df.FieldValue
    };
```

Of course if you set up navigation properties, you can just do this:

```
var results = 
    from d in dbContext.Documents
    let df = d.DocumentFields.First(x => x.RowNo == 1 && x.ColumnNo == 2)
    select new 
    {
        Document = d,
        DocumentName = df.FieldValue
    };
```